# Exception: server certificate change is restricted during renegotiation

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I get this exception:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: server certificate change is restricted during renegotiation

I found that I have to change client check to allow renegotiation with these properties:

- `Djdk.tls.allowUnsafeServerCertChange=true`
- `Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true`

But where these properties should be added?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using eclipse as client:
you need to add it in the

> Run>Run Configurations>Arguments tab> VM arguments

if you're using command line:

> java -Djdk.tls.allowUnsafeServerCertChange=true
>   -Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true -jar yourjarfile.jar

For Jboss you can add it in

> standalone.conf

file and restart your server.
For tomcat.. hmm i think you can add it in the start up script  I have not tried that though.